# Displaying a formatted 'DateTime' in a WPF 'TextBlock'

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, converters

In my WPF application, I have a static `List<Guest>`. `Guest` has properties like `Name`, `Lastname`, `Birthday`, etc.

My question concerns `Birthday`. I would like to display `Birthday`, which is of type `DateTime`, in a `TextBlock`. The output format that I want is something like `DD/MM/YYYY`. I've thought of using a parsing approach like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(s, "yyyyMMdd").ToLocalTime()
```

Is there a better way to go that avoids this kind of parsing? For instance, does C# have a converter for `DateTime`? Note that I need to do this conversion only for output.

Comment: I'm not understanding. You want to Convert a string to a DateTime without using a Parse ? You want to write your own parse? There's a Convert.To for datetime, but internally that calls Parse.

Comment: You say `TextBlock`, so you are using WPF or Silverlight?

Comment: I use WPF in my project

Comment: I doesn´t want to parse ( e.g. String.parseString) or cast [()]it like in Java. In a school exercise we took the IValueConverter but i think with Timedate i can´t take it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The painful way is to make it manually with formatting and parsing. The elegant way is to bind your form to an object containing your properties. When using object-data binding you can specify formats. The conversions in both ways are carried out automatically.

Besides the advantage of having an automatic conversion to and from strings, you have the advantage that you can separate the business logic from your form. You can apply any logic to a property called `guest.DateOfBirth` (or just `DateOfBirth` if the logic is inside the `Guest` class), for instance, instead of applying it to a construct like `DateTime.Parse(textBox13.Text)`, which makes it a lot easier to understand and maintain the code.

See:

[Data Binding for Windows Forms](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84476/data-binding-for-windows-forms/) (on developerfusion)

[Data binding concepts in .NET windows forms](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3665/Data-binding-concepts-in-NET-windows-forms) (on CodeProject)